# External monitor not working

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

Recently I've bought my first Macbook Pro 14'' and an external monitor ViewSonic VP 2785-4k. I've managed to connect the monitor to my Windows PC with HDMI/Display Port. But the MacBook doesn't see it thru the USB-C cord (it was with a monitor). The monitor says "No Signal", and the Mac doesn't show any monitors except built-in. It works if I use HDMI. But I need a USB-C connection to use my keyboard and mouse and charge. I don't have another USB-C monitor to test, unfortunately. So I ordered an Apple USB-C cord to be sure that the problem was not in the cord. Do you have any other advice on what can be done to get rid of the problem?

So I've spent some time finding a monitor that can be used both with my PC & Macbook. This one has a built-in KVM switch. I've seen some reviews and there and in monitor instruction is said that it is compatible with macOS and it should work but it's not.

UPD: I've received Apple USB-C <-> USB-C cable and it looks like it works!.

Comment: You don't see whether it works with the Apple UBS-C cable (probably not). What is at the other end of these USB-C connectors you are using? Is this direct USB-C -to- USB-C? Do you need to change the input in the configuration directly on the screen?

Comment: It's USB-C - USB-C. I've tried to change the input configuration directly on the screen. The screen becomes black for some time then the label "No Signal" appears. And then the monitor turns off. I've tried all macbook's usb-c ports. The monitor has only one USB-C port.

Comment: I read about some usb-c cables having problems. Have a look if your MacBook charger has a usb-c cable that you could try. For a short time only obviously; if that works then it’s the cable’s fault.

Comment: My charger cable is mag-safe. But I've already ordered Apple thunderbolt-3 cable. Hope that will help.